# How to use dct2() in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to pass a matrix to dct2 function but it is showing error. I am using matlab version R2012a. I have a matrix B which just used as argument like below

```
B = dct2(A);

disp(B);
```

Error is showing like this

```
Undefined function 'dct2' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Error in image_dct (line 24)
B = dct2(A);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the image processing toolkit in order to use that. Assuming you have that, then it should be just as simple as you listed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have any idea why am i getting this error? how to solve this?

Comment: But the image processing toolkit, and make sure it is installed correctly.

Comment: i can use dct() but just getting error for dct2(). In command prompt i wrote ver and got the out as->> ver
MATLAB Version: 7.14.0.739 (R2012a)
MATLAB License Number: 277316
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java Version: Java 1.6.0_17-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode
----
MATLAB                                                Version 7.14       (R2012a)
Signal Processing Toolbox                             Version 6.17       (R2012a)
Wavelet Toolbox                                       Version 4.9        (R2012a)

Comment: Dct is a part of the signal processing toolkit, which you have.

Comment: thanks but is there any way of installing image processing toolkit?